# Resolution of the G281UV Monitor Does Not Change to 3840 x 2160

Tags: hdmi, resolution

I have an HP EliteBook 830 G6 notebook with an Intel Core i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz processor and Intel UHD Graphics 620, which, according to the manufacturer, has the capability to support 4k resolution at 60hz. I tested it on a 4k resolution television using the HDMI inputs (along with the cable that came with the MSI monitor), and indeed, the resolution was satisfactory.

The issue arises with the MSI G281UV monitor, which has a 4k resolution. When using the HDMI cable that came with it, the maximum resolution achieved is only 2560 x 1440. I am unable to change it in any way. I tried another cable I have (HDMI - USB Type C) in the USB-C Thunderbolt port, and it allowed me to change the resolution to 3840 x 2160. However, the monitor displays the message "LIMIT EXCEEDED!" when attempting to make this modification.

All the drivers for my notebook are up-to-date, and I am running Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (64-bit). I have been unable to find a solution so far, including the driver for this monitor. While there were no issues with the 4k TV, the MSI monitor presents this problem.

Please assist me in finding a solution.